# libcurl - произвольный запрос

Tags: c++, c, curl

Подскажите пожалуйста, позволяет ли libcurl - отсылать произвольный запрос данных, ну к примеру "Hello net" и так же принимать все данные.

Ну для примера, записать в буфер свой Get-запрос и получить в буфер ответ от сервера и принять и  разобрать http-загловки самому ?
Из примеров и документации не понял этого момента, везде примеры только готовых запросов в рамках какого то протокола.

Comment: Оно для того и создавалось, чтобы было можно.

Comment: @Михаил Алексеевич, а не подскажете ссылку на пример, где показывается, как это возможно сделать ?

Comment: ¿Если хотите все сами разбирать, то зачем нужен Libcurl? Берите обычные сокеты.

Comment: @user7860670, да и правда, но, если бы libcurl такое мог бы - было бы попроще.

Comment: из `man curl`: `curl  is  a tool to transfer data from or to a server, using one of the supported protocols (DICT, FILE, FTP, FTPS, GOPHER, HTTP, HTTPS,  IMAP, IMAPS,  LDAP,  LDAPS,  MQTT, POP3, POP3S, RTMP, RTMPS, RTSP, SCP, SFTP, SMB, SMBS, SMTP, SMTPS, TELNET and TFTP)`. других протоколов программа (и библиотека, на функциональости которой она основана), не поддерживает.

Comment: @aleksandr barakin, а libcurl multi_socket - не в эту тему ?

Answer (score 0):

> Подскажите пожалуйста, позволяет ли libcurl - отсылать произвольный запрос данных, ну к примеру "Hello net" и так же принимать все данные.

Если подразумевается отправка сырых данных данных на транспортном уровне, то нет, разумными средствами в рамках libcurl это невозможно. Для этого есть уровень сокетов.

> Ну для примера, записать в буфер свой Get-запрос и получить в буфер ответ от сервера и принять и разобрать http-загловки самому ?

HTTP-заголовок ответа можно получить, установив свой колбек в параметр [`CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`](https://curl.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION.html).

Comment: нет, нет, речь не про RAW-сокеты. Речь просто про произвольный буфер, который можно отправить на указанный URL, и сооветвенно произвольно принять ответ от сервера так же в буфер, то есть это не обязательно будет ответ по HTTP. В общем можно ли с помощью Libcurl создать свой текстовый протокол по сути ?

Comment: нет, нельзя. часть урла записывается внутри http запроса. и если у Вас там свои данные, то и урла как такого нет

Comment: @Optimus1, я и не говорил про RAW-сокеты... но, опять же, нет: AFAIK curl не предусматривает добавление пользовательских протоколов со стороны программ. Для создания своего протокола нужно что-то более низкоуровневое... иди же можно, конечно, изменить саму библиотеку и добавить поддержку протокола в неё...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, а libcurl multi_socket - не в эту тему ?

Comment: судя по описанию — нет… это чтобы сокеты управляемые curl'ом добавлять в свои `poll`/`select`, а когда на них произойдёт событие, то можно проинформировать об этом curl, вызвав эту функция...